# How To Define Image For Self Hosted K8s Github Actions Runner

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, github-actions, devops, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

**Prerequisite**:
I created self hosted k8s github actions runner using this instructions using this tutorial https://blog.opstree.com/2023/04/18/github-self-hosted-runner-on-kubernetes/comment-page-1/ . I succeed [image]

---

**Problem**:
I need this runner for automation tests, written in Java and Selenide. So for my test executions at CI I need browsers to be installed on the runner. There is nice image "circleci/openjdk:17-jdk-buster-browsers" that I could use for such purpose. But I'm not sure how to define runner to be created using specific image. Can you suggest how to solve such demand?

---